# Graphql Cant Return Array

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am using `Apollo-Server` and trying to create a REST query against the [IEX REST API](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#company) which returns back data that looks like this:

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
  "exchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
  "industry": "Computer Hardware",
  "website": "http://www.apple.com",
  "description": "Apple Inc is an American multinational technology company. It designs, manufactures, and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers, and portable digital music players.",
  "CEO": "Timothy D. Cook",
  "issueType": "cs",
  "sector": "Technology",
  "tags": [
      "Technology",
      "Consumer Electronics",
      "Computer Hardware"
  ]
}
```

I am using [datasources](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources.html). My `typeDefs` and `resolvers` look something like this:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query{
        stock(symbol:String): Stock
    }

    type Stock {
        companyName: String
        exchange: String
        industry: String
        tags: String!
    }
`;
const resolvers = {
    Query:{
        stock: async(root, {symbol}, {dataSources}) =>{
            return dataSources.myApi.getSomeData(symbol)
        }
    }
};
```

The Datasource file looks like this:

```
class MyApiextends RESTDataSource{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.baseURL = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0';
    }

    async getSomeData(symbol){
        return this.get(`/stock/${symbol}/company`)
    }
}

module.exports = MyApi
```

I can run a query and get data back, but it is not formatting in an array and is throwing an error when I run a query like so:

```
query{
  stock(symbol:"aapl"){
    tags
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "stock": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "String cannot represent value: [\"Technology\", \"Consumer Electronics\", \"Computer Hardware\"]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "stock",
        "tags"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: String cannot represent value: [\"Technology\", \"Consumer Electronics\", \"Computer Hardware\"]",
```

The data I am expecting (technology, consumer electronics, and computer hardware) are correct, but not returning in an array. I tried to make a new `type` for tags, and set the it with a tag property, but the value just returns `null`.

I am very new to graphql, so any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to see your datasource code as well. Can you update your question to include that as well?

Comment: Ok I added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your type definition for `Stock`, you're defining the type for the `tags` field as `String!`:

```
tags: String!
```

That tells GraphQL to expect a String value that will not be null. The actual data being returned by the REST endpoint, however, is not a String -- it's an array of Strings. So your definition should minimally look like this:

```
tags: [String]
```

If you want GraphQL to throw if the tags value is null, add an exclamation point to the end to make it non-nullable:

```
tags: [String]!
```

If you want GraphQL to throw if any of the values **inside** the array are null, add an exclamation point inside the brackets. You can also combine the two:

```
tags: [String!]!
```